# What backlit ergonomic wireless keyboards options are out there?

Tags: wireless, keyboards, ergonomics

So I've been looking for a long time and I can't seem to find a keyboard that matches what I want. Maybe I'm in the huge minority or something, but I feel like someone must want this like I do....

Anyways I'm looking for a keyboard that fits the following specifications:

- Wireless
- Backlit
- Ergonomic
- Full Size
- Numpad (Bonus)

I currently use a [Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012). I really do like it for a number of reasons, but it's not backlit and it's not wireless.

It's just so that when I'm at my workstation I can set down my laptop and be good to go. I've tried a bunch of online exclusive places like Amazon, NewEgg, etc. and all the big chain places like Fry's and Best Buy. But I haven't seen one... and I'm not saying that I haven't seen some super expensive crazy custom one, or some questionable brand no one has heard of. I'm saying I haven't found a single one at all that has these specs...

Comment: Can someone explain why I got a -1? I was directed to this site when I posted my question elsewhere. I thought this was a rather direct, well researched, specific question.... if there isn't one out there that's one thing.  But what did I do wrong with my question?

Comment: If the keypad were detached from the board, like it would lay on your desk next to the keyboard as a standalone unit, would that be an acceptable compromise provided that all of your other specs are met?

Comment: I think you are going to have a tough time finding this. I am not sure if I have even seen a wireless back-lit keyboard. But then again, I haven't looked for those either.

Comment: A detached numpad would still work. There are plenty of back-lit wireless keyboards but most of them are pretty small and don't have a numpad, and none of them are ergonomic.

Comment: Maybe I could use a bluetooth transmitter but those seem pretty hard to find. I only can find two brands and both are out of stock on their respective sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ProtoArc® EK01 Advanced Ergonomic Split Keyboard](https://www.protoarc.com/collections/trending/products/ek01-advanced-ergonomic-split-keyboard) seems to meet all your listed requirements.

(I realize this answer may be a about five years late. However, I don't think a keyboard that with every feature listed existed at the time you posted the question. Even now, the EK01 is still the only keyboard I've seen, so I thought I might mention it, if it should still be of interest to you or others.)

Comment: That is a great find! I'll definitely be switching to that on my next setup... but that probably won't be for 4 years.